# Unique id of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

Does each column of a table in SQL Server have a unique id? I've looked into sys.columns and the column_id there is merely the order of the columns which changes if the order of the column is changed. I'd like to know if SQL Server maintains a unique id for each column as it does for each table and other objects. And if it does, how can I get that? Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity may I know for what reason you might be using those unique ids for? You can also get columns from information_schema.Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Oracle maintains a unique id of a column (Progress database does this as well), but SQL Server does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a column which table A and B both contains, you could use

```
SELECT A.col or B.col
```

However if you are trying to get the unique id from the master control, it seems not really possible for SQL server